# Python curses reading a single character from stdin affects output from print statement

Tags: python, curses

I'm trying to do a non-blocking read of a single character from stdin.  I have found a solution with the curses library, but I'm doing something wrong when trying to write output back to stdout.

```
import curses
from time import sleep

def callback(screen):
  screen.nodelay(1)
  return screen.getkey()

while 1:
  try:
    key = curses.wrapper(callback)
    print "Got keypress: ", key
  except:
    sleep(3)
    print "No Keypress"
    print "Program\nOutput"

# Prints
No Keypress
          Program
                  Output
```

Everything works flawlessly with the exception of the indented output.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that using curses, '\n' is just a form feed. You presumably need to output a carriage return as well, or else explicitly use curses to reposiition the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

In the case proper `curses` window is started, only `screen.addch('\n')` worked for me (in which case, both the carriage return and the line feed are printed); I couldn't get `print` (or rather, `sys.stdout.write`) to "behave", even with specifying `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
#youres to use
import curses
from time import sleep

def callback(screen):
  screen.nodelay(1)
  return screen.getkey()

def getkey():
  try:
    key = curses.wrapper(callback)
  except:
    key = None
  return key

#tryer
while 1:
  sleep(1)
  k= getkey()
  if k != None:
    print "goo", k
  else:
    print "foo"
```

Comment: some explanation what you changed would be nice